# How to pause video when click on new tab using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, visibilitychange

I'am working on video HTML Tag i want pause the audio when new Tab is open. Pls help to fix this issue.

```
<video autoplay onplay="clickplayer()" id="player" onended="endplayer()" fullscreen="true" controls onvolumechange="myFunction()"  ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime) + ' / ' + Math.floor(this.duration);">dik</video>
```

Comment: Do you want pause audio and keep video playing or both pause?

Answer (score 6):

You need to detect the window de-focus event first to do so. Here is an example:

**HTML:**

```
 <video id="video" width="400" controls>
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

**JS:**

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
function onchange (evt) {
   document.getElementById("video").pause();
}
```

You can find full example [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/krunal2450/ty0vkbbk/)

> Note that, same method applies to Audio tags as well.

Answer (score 3):

> The [`visibilitychange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange) event is fired when the content of a tab has become visible or has been hidden.

You should detect tab visibility on `visibilitychange` event and pause video if tab is hidden.

```js
var focused = true;
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {
  focused = !focused;
  if (!focused)
    document.getElementById("video").pause();
});
```

```html
<video id="video" width="400" controls>
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```